# find and replace image src on click

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
 <div class="checkbox" rel="1" id="fr2"><img src="images/checkbox_off.png" class="ckbox" width="16" height="16">1917</div>
<div class="checkbox" rel="2" id="fr2"><img src="images/checkbox_off.png" class="ckbox" width="16" height="16">1957</div>
<div class="checkbox" rel="3" id="fr2"><img src="images/checkbox_off.png" class="ckbox" width="16" height="16">1997</div>
<input type="text" name="fr2_val" id="fr2_val" value="">
```

On Click on one of this checkbox div i want to change the image of this clicked onw:

Thats my jQuery:

```
$('.checkbox').click(function() {
            var wert = $(this).attr('rel');
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#'+id+'_val').val(wert);

            $(this).find('.ckbox').src.replace("_off", "_on");
        })
```

But it doesn't work right. How can i change the clicked image src? And how is the best solution to reset the other ones?

thanks for help

best regards
thomas

Comment: I'd also like to point out that your `id`s should be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assigned the changed src back to checkbox, you get a string by  `$(this).find('.ckbox').src` and changing it wont change the src of actual checkbox.

```
chkbox = $(this).find('.ckbox');
chkbox.attr('src', chkbox.prop('src').replace("_off", "_on"));
```

or using the DOM object instead of jQuery object. You can directly access src and change it.

```
chkbox = $(this).find('.ckbox')[0];
chkbox.src = chkbox.src.replace("_off", "_on");
```

Beside this I could not understand why you are making the id dynamically for input with id `fr2_val`